# Xen limit incoming traffic speed

Tags: xen, bandwidth-control

I've tried using 'rate' to limit the traffic speed of a VM inside the config file but that only limits the outgoing traffic speed of traffic from the VM. I want to limit the speed traffic can flow both ways.

Thanks

Comment: how do you do limit it?

Comment: @silviud I use the 'limit' setting in the Xen VM config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use XEN 4.2.2 at the time of this reply.

- Remove rate=X from your guest config file and shut it down.
- Make sure your kernel have at least the following enabled:
- IP: advanced router
- TCP: advanced congestion control (all options enabled)
- QoS and/or fair queueing (all options enabled expect the debug ones)
- Install 'tc' command
- Verify it's working by running: tc -s qdisc ls dev eth0

If you get no errors, you're ready to modify /etc/xen/scripts/vif-bridge

Find this word 'online)'

Just add before `;;`

```
tc qdisc add dev "$dev" root tbf rate 120mbit burst 20mbit latency 5ms peakrate 125mbit minburst 20mbit mpu 64
```

So the modified version of vif-bridge should look like this:

```
online)        
        setup_virtual_bridge_port "$dev"

        mtu="`ip link show $bridge | awk '/mtu/ { print $5 }'`"

        if [ -n "$mtu" ] && [ "$mtu" -gt 0 ]

        then

                ip link set $dev mtu $mtu || :

        fi         

        add_to_bridge "$bridge" "$dev"

        tc qdisc add dev "$dev" root tbf rate 120mbit burst 20mbit latency 5ms peakrate 125mbit minburst 20mbit mpu 64

        ;;
```

Find this word 'offline)'

Append to first line: do_without_error tc qdisc del dev "$dev" root

```
offline)
        do_without_error tc qdisc del dev "$dev" root

        do_without_error brctl delif "$bridge" "$dev"

        do_without_error ifconfig "$dev" down

        ;;
```

Using the above TBF rule your guest should have roughly 12.5MB/s upload and 14.0M/s download speed; a bit over 120Mbps

If you upload/download same time, both upload and download speed should be about 7.5MB/s ~ 150Mbps total bandwidth

This is what I got after an hour tweaking. If you find better values; please let us know

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure of a way to limit the inbound traffic to a Xen DomU (which is actually what you claim to have already done), I have limited outbound traffic in the past by making a very simple change to the vif definition in my DomU's config file. For example, for one guest, I am using:

```
vif = [ 'rate=5Mb/s , bridge=xenbr0' ]
```

Like I said, though, this will only limit the rate of outbound traffic.

I've also read (but haven't tried) that you have the option of specifying a time window to tweak the latency/throughput, as well, with a syntax like the following:

```
vif = [ 'rate=5Mb/s@25ms , bridge=xenbr0' ]
```

---

Reference:
http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Tips_and_tricks-Limit_network_bandwidth_for_a_Xen_guest.html

Comment: You are right - rate limits outbound, not inbound. I corrected the question.